# Limits with omitted x

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I've come across this exercise.

> Calculate the limit: $$\lim_{x}\frac{\ln{2^{\frac{1}{x}}}-\ln{x^2}}{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{x}}$$

Note that the value to which $x$ approaches is omitted. Is this malformed expression or should we assume the value it should approach?

Edit: From the series, it does look like here $x\rightarrow\infty$, but is there a general consensus for this?

Comment: I guess is $n\to\infty$ instead of $x$

Comment: Just from how the expression looks, and especially the denominator, I would assume that it is $x \to \infty$

Comment: @sinbadh sorry I mistyped, it should be $x$ instead of $n$. I should still use $x\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: Yes. Use $x\to\infty$ and $x\in\mathbb{N}$

Comment: As the other comments say, it looks like just a typo, because otherwise it's meaningless. From the denominator we surmise that it should say $x\to \infty.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything else than $x\to\infty$ looks unreasonable.

From the denominator we would conclude that $x$ is a positive integer, that's how $\cdots$ are interpreted. And given that we have an expression or function $f(n)$ that depends on a positive we would have $\lim_{n\to a}f(n) = f(a)$ if $a$ is a positive integer. And if $a$ is non-positive integer or not an integer at all it would be undefined.

The only thing left becomes $x\to+\infty$.

Formally it's malformed since $\cdots$ is not a formally defined, but it requires the reader to see the same pattern as the author and would then be interpreted as something formally defined depending on that interpretation. In his case $1+1/2+1/3+\cdots+1/x$ would by most persons be interpreted as $\sum_{j=1}^x 1/k$.

Otherwise as a function from $\mathbb N$ it could be well formed to just use the notation $\lim_x f(n)$ for the above mentioned reason (look in the book and see if it's defined somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Consider that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $n_0$ such that
$$
\frac{(2-\varepsilon)\ln x}{(1+\varepsilon) \ln x}\le \frac{\frac{1}{x}\ln 2+2\ln x}{1+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}} \le \frac{(2+\varepsilon)\ln x}{(1-\varepsilon) \ln x}
$$
for all $n\ge n_0$, therefore the limit is $2$.

Comment: I don't think this is a question about how to _calculate_ the limit. Also note that you have the wrong sign in the numerator. Otherwise, nice solution.